# Update Glue job parameter using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3, aws-glue

I need to update a Glue job parameter but the code is not working.

How can I update a job parameter in AWS Glue using Boto3? This code didn't work:

```
response = glue_client.get_job(JobName=glue_job_name)
job = response['Job']
job['DefaultArguments'][parameter_name] = new_parameter_value
glue_client.update_job(JobName=glue_job_name, JobUpdate=job)`
```

I got this error:

```json
{
  "statusCode": 500,
  "body": "Error: Parameter validation failed:\nUnknown parameter in JobUpdate: \"Name\", must be one of: Description, LogUri, Role, ExecutionProperty, Command, DefaultArguments, NonOverridableArguments, Connections, MaxRetries, AllocatedCapacity, Timeout, MaxCapacity, WorkerType, NumberOfWorkers, SecurityConfiguration, NotificationProperty, GlueVersion, CodeGenConfigurationNodes, ExecutionClass, SourceControlDetails\nUnknown parameter in JobUpdate: \"CreatedOn\", must be one of: Description, LogUri, Role, ExecutionProperty, Command, DefaultArguments, NonOverridableArguments, Connections, MaxRetries, AllocatedCapacity, Timeout, MaxCapacity, WorkerType, NumberOfWorkers, SecurityConfiguration, NotificationProperty, GlueVersion, CodeGenConfigurationNodes, ExecutionClass, SourceControlDetails\nUnknown parameter in JobUpdate: \"LastModifiedOn\", must be one of: Description, LogUri, Role, ExecutionProperty, Command, DefaultArguments, NonOverridableArguments, Connections, MaxRetries, AllocatedCapacity, Timeout, MaxCapacity, WorkerType, NumberOfWorkers, SecurityConfiguration, NotificationProperty, GlueVersion, CodeGenConfigurationNodes, ExecutionClass, SourceControlDetails\nUnknown parameter in JobUpdate.Command: \"test_parameter\", must be one of: Name, ScriptLocation, PythonVersion, Runtime"
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: What did not work?

Comment: I have added the error in the description

Comment: The error message is quite clear, do not specify the `Name` as part of the `JobUpdate`.

Answer (score 1):

The response from `glue_client.get_job` contains the following attributes that `glue_client.update_job` doesn't accept:

```
Job.Name
Job.CreatedOn
Job.LastModifiedOn
```

You can remove these attributes from the job using the `del` keyword:

```py
response = glue_client.get_job(JobName=glue_job_name)
job = response['Job']

# Remove redundant attributes
del job['Name']
del job['CreatedOn']
del job['LastModifiedOn']

job['DefaultArguments'][parameter_name] = new_parameter_value
glue_client.update_job(JobName=glue_job_name, JobUpdate=job)`
```